# Inserting more values than columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm studying at this Oracle insert statement(part of a larger set  of inserts , for conversion purposes )  :

```
Insert into LEGACYD.CV_ACCT_PER_POI 
    (ACCT_ID, 
     ACCT_REL_TYPE_CD,
     BILL_ADDR_SRCE_FLG,
     PER_ID,MAIN_CUST_SW,
     FIN_RESP_SW,THRD_PTY_SW,
     RECEIVE_COPY_SW,
     BILL_RTE_TYPE_CD,
     BILL_FORMAT_FLG,
     NBR_BILL_COPIES,
     VERSION,
     CUST_PO_ID,
     NOTIFY_SW,
     NAME_PFX_SFX,
     PFX_SFX_FLG,
     QTE_RTE_TYPE_CD,
     RECV_QTE_SW,
     WEB_ACCESS_FLG) 

values ('4106635799',
        'MAIN    ',
        'ACOV',
        '9318753586',
        'Y',
        'Y',
        'N',
        'Y',
        'EDI     ',
        'D ',
        1,
        2,
        ' ',
        'Y',
        ' ',
        '  ',
        '            ',
        'N',
        'ALWD');
```

After the insert into commands, we have 17 columns being listed. But then there are 19 values being put into those 17 columns? How can you insert more values than columns?

Comment: There are 19 columns. Four are just squished onto two lines: `PER_ID,MAIN_CUST_SW` and `FIN_RESP_SW,THRD_PTY_SW`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closer - you have 19 columns and 19 values. There are two lines in the INSERT statement where two columns are listed:

```
 PER_ID,MAIN_CUST_SW,  
 FIN_RESP_SW,THRD_PTY_SW,
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 PER_ID,MAIN_CUST_SW,                <-- 2 fields
 FIN_RESP_SW,THRD_PTY_SW,            <-- 2 fields
```

...so basically a formatting issue, both have 19 fields.